# PowerShell Local Network IP Information

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a list of all devices connected on my home network. So far I have used the get-neighbor command to retrieve IP addresses. Is there a way I can find the name of the devices on the network either with their IP addresses or any other way.

This is on PowerShell v5

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look into nslookup IP-ADDRESS. You can parse the hostname from the Name section.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200525

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it this way to get the name:

```
[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress($ip)
```